# Workflow to copy field between lists

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I have 2 lists:

- "General information"(contains field "Current kilometers"(number), "Registration number")
- "Maintenance" (contains field "Kilometres"(number), "Registration Number"(lookup) )

I wanted to create a Workflow so that when the user updates an item in "General information", the value of the "Current kilometres" is to be copied to the "Kilometres" field in the "Maintenance" list.

**What I did**:

- I created a new Workflow for the "General information" list
- I made it to activate on Item Updating
- Then I clicked "this list" and selected as list "Maintenance". I clicked "Add" and in the "Set this field" I chose "Kilometres"; I set "To this value" to: Data source: Current Item, Field from sorce: Current kilometers.
- Then in the section "Find the List Item" I chose Field:Registration Number(the lookup) and Value: Data source: Current Item, Field: Registration Number.

I clicked ok, save, publish. Then tried to update an item in the General information list. Nothing happened to the field in the Maintenance list.

**Other Info**:

- I created the workflow in the SharePoint Designer 2010;
- A lookup field to view the data to the other list is not an option. It has to be done in a workflow.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the following steps:

1. Read the current list and save the values of Current kilometers and Registration Number in two varibales.
2. Now use the Update Listiem activity and in List option choose "Maintainance" and update the field Kilometres and in the find listitm section use Registration Number

[image]

Correct me if i am wrong anywhere.